# Ubuntu22.04 で解像度がWQHD対応にならない

Tags: ubuntu

### 質問

UbuntuのデスクトップPCを外付けディスプレイに接続しているのですが、解像度をWQHDの解像度にする方法を教えてください。

### 環境

- OS：Ubuntu 22.04.01
- GPU

```
$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)
```

- ドライバ
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- ディスプレイ：WQHD(2560×1440)が1枚
- HDMIケーブル：4K対応しているもの([これです](https://www.amazon.co.jp/5%E7%A8%AE%E9%95%B7%E3%81%95%E3%80%91iVANKY-HDMI2-0%E8%A6%8F%E6%A0%BC-Nintendo-TV%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E9%81%A9%E7%94%A818gbps-%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%9F%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A0/dp/B07RHHB1MJ/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=D8XRr&content-id=amzn1.sym.0497a660-dd67-4204-8041-89ed368b6fd7&pf_rd_p=0497a660-dd67-4204-8041-89ed368b6fd7&pf_rd_r=0TJFJ1A0W6KVD8C61Z4X&pd_rd_wg=dRFyI&pd_rd_r=d0bd5a90-9ed4-4b1f-a7d5-184370e70efc&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_atf_m))

### やったこと

1. WQHD対応の確認
   GPUとHDMIケーブルがWQHDに対応しているか確認しました。
   Geforce RTX3060と私の使用しているHDMIケーブルはどちらもWQHDに対応しているようでした。
2. 設定からの変更
   Ubuntuの設定から解像度の変更をしようとしましたが、1920x1080以外が選択できない状態でした。
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
3. /etc/default/grubの変更

`/etc/default/grub`を編集し、
`GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440`として保存。

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ reboot
```

を実行しましたが、再起動後はなぜか解像度が1024x768になってしまいました。なので、`GRUB_GFXMODE`の値はもともとの1920x1080に戻しました。

4. ドライバの変更
   上でドライバの情報を載せましたが、もともとはデフォルトで「X.Org X server - Nouveau display dirverをxserver-xorg-video-nouveauから使用します(オープンソース)」が選択されていました。
   軽くネットを見た限りだとこれでは対応する解像度に制限がありそうだったので、上記にキャプチャで載せているドライバに変更してみました。
5. もう一度手順3を実行しました。
6. xrandrに新しい解像度を追加する

```
$ cvt 2560 1440
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493
xrandr:Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

`xrandr --newmode`で新しいモードを追加しようとすると怒られました。

### その他

ドライバの設定等が関係あるのか？と考えていますが、その方面に詳しくないため、詳しい方にお力をいただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

参考にしたサイト
https://qiita.com/nsd24/items/c06294d1de40f2e9870b
https://blog.capilano-fw.com/?p=1881

Comment: [こちら](https://qiita.com/y-vectorfield/items/72bfb66d8ec85847fe2f)を参考に、nvidia-driver-525をインストールしたところ、設定から2560x1440が設定できるようになりました！！

Answer (score 4):

自己解決しました。ドライバが正しくインストールできていなかったようです。

参考：
[【注意】ubuntu-drivers devicesでお薦めされたNVIDIA GPUドライバーをインストールしたら事故になります。](https://qiita.com/y-vectorfield/items/72bfb66d8ec85847fe2f)

**インストール前:**

```
$ nvidia-smi
No devices were found
```

ドライバインストール後は以下のように出力されるようになりました。

**インストール後:**

```
Sat Jan  7 11:43:20 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.11    Driver Version: 525.60.11    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P8    13W / 170W |    405MiB / 12288MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1717      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                185MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1874      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               90MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2325      G   ...RendererForSitePerProcess       25MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3359      G   gnome-control-center               14MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3482    C+G   ...160814179602901050,131072       84MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```